# Enabling OAuth at Operation level in Azure api management

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

Regarding Azure management services, 
I wanted to enable Oauth authentication for selective operations in my API group.

I see the option only at API level and not at operation level. Is there a way to achieve at operation level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks cannot we cannot enable oauth at operation level.

(Copying from comments)

Lets say I have 3 operations in api group called MyAPI. Now I want to enable OAuth authentication only for 2 operations. Is this possible ?

```
Not currently. You can only associate auth server with an API and when you do so console will render auth UI for all operations in that API. Thanks @Vitaliy Kurokhtin
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have configured your OAuth 2.0 authorization server and configured your API to use that server, you can test it by going to the Developer Portal and calling an API. Click **Developer portal** in the top menu from your Azure API Management instance **Overview** page.

Click **APIs** in the top menu and select Your_API.

Select the `GET Resource` operation, click **Open Console**, and then select **Authorization code** from the drop-down.

[image]

When Authorization code is selected, a pop-up window is displayed with the sign-in form of the OAuth 2.0 provider. In this example the sign-in form is provided by Azure Active Directory.
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2).

Comment: Thanks! Let me check the article

Comment: Lets say I have 3 operations in api group called MyAPI. Now I want to enable OAuth authentication only for 2 operations. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not currently. You can only associate auth server with an API and when you do so console will render auth UI for all operations in that API.